# bootstrap Glyphicons

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Bootstrap css uses the halflings from [Glyphicons](http://glyphicons.com/).
If I purchased their full product line, how would I incorporate that into the bootstrap framework?

Comment: I asked the artist, and he said "I'm glad that you're interested in Glyphicons! Regarding your question: at this time, there is nothing like ALL Glyphicons in Twitter's Bootstrap, but it's good idea, I'll be think about it."

Comment: Hi @phillip did you ever end up modifying the .less file for this?  Mind sharing, if you did?

Comment: Nah, I just kept moving on.  I was just wondering, but it wasn't a requirement.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You would have to recalculate the background positioning of every glyph icon into your own class or overwrite the classes already set by the bootstrap in order to work them in. Twitter's bootstrap uses the halfling (free) version of the icons which are 14px all around, the full set is double the size so the old `background-position's` won't work.

Here is an example of what one of the bootstraps icon classes looks like:

```
/* class for the icon "fast-backward", notice the positioning values set in pixels */
.icon-fast-backward {
    background-position: -216px -72px;
}

/* main class, defining what icon sheet to use */
[class^="icon-"], [class*=" icon-"] {
    background-image: url("../img/glyphicons-halflings.png");
    background-position: 14px 14px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 14px;
    line-height: 14px;
    vertical-align: text-top;
    width: 14px;
}
```

Answer (score 57):

Use this [CSS sprite generator](http://spritegen.website-performance.org/), uploading the zip file. It will create the relevant CSS classes for you (names are taken from images itself), merging all images in one (transparent) PNG one.

Comment: Excellent suggestion Gremo, this tool will do it all for you.

Comment: Gremo, you totally rock.  Using your suggestion I was able to create a setup for glyphicons-free for my site.  Now I have 420 icons for use.  My steps for anyone else: I removed 'glyphicons-###_' from the filenames and scaled the images down 56% to make them match the existing bootstrap glyphicons setup.

Comment: gremo--I just found this topic and have to thank you for this. That sprite generator is super awesome. Truly amazing. Thank you very very much!

Answer (score 37):

You could also use the [Font Awesome](http://fortawesome.github.com/Font-Awesome/) solution.

> Scalable vector graphics means icons look awesome at any size.
>
> Designed from scratch to be fully backwards compatible with Twitter Bootstrap 2.0.

Comment: actually I've found it renders quite poor at small sizes.

Comment: Also the icons are different widths, so layout-wise they are useless.

Comment: This is the right direction to go! As many others I thought that I will mess up everything using it. Well, read the home page, as I did, it's just integrate with bootstrap very well. Many thanks.

Comment: You somehow missed the question. While Font Awesome really IS awesome, the OP bought Glyphicons and wants to use them. So suggesting other icon fonts won't help him.

Answer (score 7):

I have also created one on Github. Didn't see Marco's post above until after.

https://github.com/ekryski/bootstrap-template

Comment: Thank you very much ekryski!  I've recently learned about unicode and am wondering why a framework such as bootstrap isn't utilizing it, unless they feel that their sprite will be consistent across browsers.

Comment: Oh, I see Marco's comment to my comment above.

Answer (score 6):

From what I recall, Glyphicons doesn't provide their icons as a sprite version (many icons as one image), instead you get each icon separately.  If you only plan on using a couple of their icons, this should be ok.

The best way would be to create a separate css file and continue on with their ".icon-" naming convention.

```
.icon-whatever {
   background:url('..img/someicon.png') 0 0; 
}
```

The default background position is `14px 14px` so you need to reset it to `0 0` like I did above.

Comment: The Bootstrap version is definitely a sprite.

Comment: Bootstrap's may be, but Makotosan is correct, Glyphicons pro is not distributed with a sprite image. Here is a generator/css for the pngs provided by the Glyphicons Pro zip file. https://gist.github.com/2694578

Answer (score 5):

I've created a sprite and CSS drop-in for Bootstrap to provide this functionality. The repo and instructions are on [Github](http://marcoceppi.github.com/bootstrap-glyphicons). Not every icon has coverage yet, and some are still slightly off-center. To use the bigger icons just add the `icon-large` CSS class:

```
<i class="icon-large icon-search"></i>
```

Comment: Thank you Marco!  I just noticed too that there are quite a few icons in unicode.  I wonder why bootstrap doesn't utilize that?  I suppose it's because they could vary from one browser to another.

Answer (score 2):

There is a great article about Bootstrap Icons here: http://www.themplio.com/twitter-bootstrap-icons

Comment: OK, great.  Hey, have you seen unicode?  I can't believe so much is built into the browser now, like: &#10004;

Comment: @Phillip, its here now - ✔ :)

Answer (score 2):

No need to incorporate it. You can just add the glyphicons and use it alongside with the halflings bootstrap comes with.

Add the glyphicons (regular set) as follows:

```
/css/glyphicons.css 
/fonts/glyphicons-regular.eot 
/fonts/glyphicons-regular.svg 
/fonts/glyphicons-regular.ttf 
/fonts/glyphicons-regular.woff 
/fonts/glyphicons-regular.woff2
```

You propably should give the base-css-class: `.glyphicons` the same style as bootstraps `.glyphicon`

```
.glyphicons {
    position:relative;
    top:2px; 
    display:inline-block;
    font-family:'Glyphicons Regular';
    font-style:normal;
    font-weight:normal;
    line-height:1;
    vertical-align:top;
    -webkit-font-smoothing:antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing:grayscale
}
```

Next, add the reference to the glyphicons into your page as follows:

```
<link href="/css/glyphicons.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Now, use the complete 'regular' glyphicons alongside with the halflings:

```
<!-- halflings / bootstrap 3 -->
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-glass"></span>

<!-- Glyphicons Regular set (note the plural suffix!) -->
<span class="glyphicons glyphicons-glass"></span>
```

The other answers are fine but keep in mind the difference between icons with the font-technique and the older technique when using sprite-png's. Png's are not always scaleable and therefore comes with several sizes. Also, the color can not be set. To contrast with the background, the `.white` class can be used on png's to switch from black to white. By using fonts, style the icons as you would style a font:

```
.iconstyle {  color: blue;  font-size: 26px;  etc.. }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use my soluce. Put this line after bootstrap link url css on your header.

```
<link href="../assets/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="../assets/css/opa-icons.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Then to call online html code

```
<i class="icon-close icon-red"></i>&nbsp;Someting <!-- 16x16pix size color red -->
<i class="icon32 icon-close icon-blue"></i>&nbsp;Someting <!-- 32x32pix size color red -->
```

You could download here the assets (images-icons png and css both in zip) :

http://www.photonautes-associes.fr/utils/assets.zip
enjoy :)

Comment: Thanks Bruno!  I'll check it out!

Answer (score 1):

Download fonts from official bootstrap page and then paste this code as is in your CSS file

Try This code

```
@font-face{
font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
src: url('/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot');}
```

Answer (score 1):

I thought I'd add my experience to the list here.

There were several obstacles for me when trying to add Glyphicons All to my existing, labyrinthine, Bootstrap-riddled codebase. (Among them, Glyphicons All uses the construction ".glyphicons .glyphicons-[name]" and Bootstrap uses the construction ".glyphicon .glyphicon-[name]").

I ultimately decided to just use them both, in parallel. Going forward, I find I'm using the Glyphicons All construction more and more, but the Bootstrap construction still works for all of my existing code.

Yes, including both "fonts" adds to the overall page weight, but not disastrously.

Comment: Thanks @skybondsor. I asked this question a few years ago. Maybe I should revisit it, but I don't know. I just settle for what's free instead of shelling out $59 to add a different icon.

Comment: I was defs satisfied with the free version for years! But recently I needed the backwards arrow icon for Twitter "reply", and figured it was probably time I kick that guy some money anyway.

Answer (score 1):

What I did was pretty simple and worked perfectly. NOTE: this is if you want those beautiful glyphicons working as fonts, as the bootstrap version I'm using does.

1. In the glyphicons zip, copy all the fonts in /glyphicons/web/bootstrap_example/fonts to where your bootstrap fonts are currently in your project
2. In the glyphicons zip, look at /web/bootstrap_example/css/glyphicons.css, copy and paste all into your own less/css file.
3. This step may be unnecessary as long as your own css/less file overwrites them properly: In your project's bootstrap.css file, remove @font-face stuff, .glyphicon styles, and all the glyphicon individual content tags (i.e, .glyphicon-xxxx:before { content: ... }).
4. In your less/css file with all the new tags, do a find and replace 
   ".glyphicons-" replace with ".glyphicon-"

That should be it, unless I'm forgetting something simple. Works great for me.

Answer (score 0):

Use [glyphicons classess](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#glyphicons-how-to-use), example:

```
`<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" aria-hidden="true"></span>`
```

My favourite icon fonts is [Fontello](http://fontello.com/), you can download icons you need instead of whole package.